# My DecagonalPrismApp won't print the output

Tags: java

I can't get the output to print, I've tried many diff. things to try and get it to print but it won't work. It's supposed to print error messages if I put in a negative # for height or edge. Also the output for valid #'s won't print either. I'm not sure where to put the block of code for that one. Can someone help me?

My Program: https://pastebin.com/D8FQv1yR

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *The App for the Decagonal Prism program.
 * @author Kathleen Tumlin - Fundamentals of Computing I - 1210
 * @version 9/17/21
 */
public class DecagonalPrismApp {
 
   //fields
   String label = "";
   double edge = 0;
   double height = 0;
   double edgeIn = 0;
   double heightIn = 0;
 
   // constuctor   
  /** Shows public decagonal prism, setLabel, and setEdge.
   * @param labelIn takes input for label in the constructor.
   * @param edgeIn takes input for the edge in the constructor.
   */
   public DecagonalPrismApp(String labelIn, double edgeIn, double heightIn) {
      setLabel(labelIn);
      setEdge(edgeIn);
      setHeight(heightIn);
   }   
 
  //methods 
  /** Shows the return for label variable.
   * @return returns the label variable.
   */
   public String getLabel() {
      return label;
   }
 
  /** Shows the set label.
   * @param labelIn takes the labelIn for the method.
   * @return returns the boolean if the variable was set.
   */
   public boolean setLabel(String labelIn) {
      if (labelIn != null) {
         label = labelIn.trim();
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;
      }
   }
 
  /** Shows the return for the edge variable.
   * @return returns the value for the variable edge.
   */
   public double getEdge() {
      return edge;
   }
 
  /** Shows the set edge.
   * @param edgeIn takes the edgein and sets it as the edge variable.
   * @return returns the boolean if the variable was set.
   */
   public boolean setEdge(double edgeIn) {
      if (edgeIn > -1) {
         edge = edgeIn;
         return true;
      } 
      else {
         System.out.println("Error: edge must be non-negative.");
         return false;
      }
   }
 
   /** Shows the return for the height variable.
    *@return returns the value for the variable edge.
    */
   public double getHeight() {
      return height;
   }
 
  /** Shows the set height.
   * @param heightIn takes the heightin and sets it as the height variable.
   * @return returns the boolean if the variable was set.
   */   
   public boolean setHeight(double heightIn) {
      if (heightIn > -1) {
         height = heightIn;
         return true;
      } 
      else {
         System.out.println("Error: height must be non-negative.");
         return false;
      }
   }
 
   public void start() {
      do {
         System.out.print("Error: height must be non-negative." );
      } while (heightIn > -1);
 
      do {
         System.out.print("Error: edge must be non-negative." );
      } while (edgeIn > -1);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   /**
    *Shows what prints.
    * @param args not used.
    */
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter label, edge, and height length for a "
         + "decagonal prism.");
      System.out.print("\tlabel: ");
      String label = scan.nextLine();
 
      System.out.print("\tedge: ");
      double edge = scan.nextDouble();
 
      System.out.print("\theight: ");
      double height = scan.nextDouble();  
 
   }
}
```

Valid #'s code: https://pastebin.com/DPuSpMEq

```
public String toString() {
      DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0##");
      return "A decagonal prism \"" + label
         + "with edge = " + edge + " units.\n\t"
         + "and height = " + height + " units.\n\t has:"
         + "surface area = " + fmt.format(surfaceArea()) + " square units\n\t"
         + "base area = " + fmt.format(baseArea()) + " square units \n\t"
         + "lateral surface area = " 
                  + fmt.format(lateralSurfaceArea()) + " square units\n\t"
         + "volume = " + fmt.format(volume()) + " cubic units \n\t";
```

Comment: You just read user inputs in the method `main` of  `DecagonalPrismApp` but you have not created any instance of the class `DecagonalPrismApp` and no setters seem to be invoked.  Please make one additional step further in your code.

Comment: Is this correct?                                                                                                             public void DecagonalPrismApp(String labelIn, double edgeIn, double heightIn) {
      setLabel(labelIn);
      setEdge(edgeIn);
      setHeight(heightIn);
   }

Comment: Here is a paste bin of the code for easier reading https://pastebin.com/Rb6SrtEZ

Comment: The constructor seems to be fine, but you need to call it at least once and create an instance of `DecagonalPrismApp` in `main` method after reading the inputs: `DecagonalPrismApp app = new DecagonalPrismApp(label, edge, height);` -- then you should see error messages printed in the console in case of wrong inputs.  After that you may call `System.out.println(app);` - this invokes overridden method `toString`.